# Ignore files when commit Android studio

Tags: android, svn, android-studio, commit, ignore

I put this line in .gitignore :

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
```

I managed to import my project on svn not include these files.
But when I want to commit, basic, all of files are checked.
Why ?

I would like unchecked these files automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using SVN (Not Git) then you need to specify the ignore files/folders in a different location.

Go to:

`File` -> `Settings`

`Version Control`-> `Ignored Files`

And add them using the plus button, selecting the desired folder / file.

[image: adding ignored files]

The files you choose are up to you. 
Above is the directory/ files i choose. Things I think are supposed to be excluded.

Note: Make sure you are selecting folders/files from the correct (current) project. As it defaulted to another project location for me at first.

Comment: There is no `Ignored Files` under `File -> Settings > Version Control` in Android Studio **2021.3.1**